# different results for the solution of bessel function with exponential

Tags: functions, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I have this integral
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}K_1(\beta \sqrt{x}) \, dx.
$$

for $\Re[\alpha] >0$, and $\Re[\beta]>0$

According to the (Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, Seventh Edition), equation 6.614.5 the solution of the above integral is:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\beta}{8\alpha^{\frac{3}{2}}} \exp \left( \frac{\beta^2}{8\alpha}\right)\left[ K_1 \left(\frac{\beta^2}{8\alpha} \right)- K_0       \left( \frac{\beta^2}{8\alpha}\right)\right] \,,
$$

However, when using Mathematica to solve the above equation we get:

$$ \frac{\pi}{2\beta\sqrt{\alpha}}   U\left(0.5,0,\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\right).$$

Why this difference?

Comment: This isn't really the right way to use the word "solution".  That seems to be a word that non-mathematicians latch onto and use whenever they don't know which word to use.  The word "value" could serve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special relation between Tricomi's U and the Bessel K functions, see e.g. http://functions.wolfram.com/07.33.03.0006.01:
$$U(a, 2 a - 1, z) = \frac{e^{\frac{z}{2}} z^{\frac{3}{2} - a}}{2(a - 1) \sqrt{\pi}}\left(K_{a - \frac{1}{2}} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right) - K_{a - \frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)$$
With your $a=1/2$ this simplifies to 
$$U\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0, z\right) = -\frac{e^{\frac{z}{2}} z}{ \sqrt{\pi}}\left(K_0 \left(\frac{z}{2}\right) - K_1\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)\cdot$$
Now substitute $z=\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}$ and multiply by 
$\frac{\pi}{2\beta\sqrt{\alpha}}$ and you get
$$\frac{\pi}{2\beta\sqrt{\alpha}} U\left(\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\beta}{8\alpha^{\frac{3}{2}}} \exp \left( \frac{\beta^2}{8\alpha}\right)\left( K_1 \left(\frac{\beta^2}{8\alpha} \right)- K_0\left( \frac{\beta^2}{8\alpha}\right)\right)\cdot$$
Therefore there is actually no difference in the results.

Comment: when you substitute `a=1/2` in this part $$ K_{a - \frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)$$ we get `-1`.

Comment: Yes, but $K_{-\nu}(z) = K_{\nu}(z),\;$ see e.g. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27.E3

Comment: Many Thanks.
your explanation is very clear.